# when ListView row item loses focus or another row is clicked go back to original state

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, android-listview

I have this activity displaying five rows of input [one, two, three...five]: 
[image]

When each row is clicked the layout changes to display EditText and a Save icon:

[image]

My problem is that if I click more than 1 row I can change many layouts like this:
[image]

I want that every time I click on a different row from ListView **if there was some row previously clicked (with EditText + Save Icon display) then change that row back to its original state (TextView + Trash and Arrow grey icon)**.

This is the custom layout for each row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listbackground"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#70000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/swipeImageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/swipe2"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:padding="5dp" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/updateEditText"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="#1f020260"
        android:textColor="#70000000"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:id="@+id/saveImageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/save"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:padding="11dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the onListItemClick() method I'm using (haven't refactored so there's some repeated code sorry for that):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final TextView rowTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    final ImageView swipeImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.swipeImageView);
    final EditText updateEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.updateEditText);
    final ImageView saveImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.saveImageView);

    rowTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    swipeImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    updateEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    saveImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    updateEditText.setText(rowTextView.getText());
    updateEditText.setFocusable(true);
    updateEditText.requestFocus();

    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(updateEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    saveImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String update = updateEditText.getText().toString();

            Product product = (Product) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

            productsDAO.updateProduct(product, update);

            rowTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            swipeImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            updateEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            saveImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            adapterUpdater.getItem(position).setName(update);
            adapterUpdater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like:

```
rowTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
           //hide the edit stuff
        }
    }
});
```